# Error: no matching Route53Zone found: when attempting to link Route53 to an Amazon load balancer

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

Let us say that I have a public hosted zone `service.example.com.`. We have this code working in a configuration that includes an API Gateway. We have decided to bind a CNAME ALIAS to an ALB/NLB that is in front of an ECS cluster. We intend to add a certificate to the ALB/NLB later on and to drop in a WAF. However, we need to get this working before moving to those.

This hosted zone is stored in a variable domain_suffix without the dot as `service.example.com`.
I am using a custom terraform module for the ALB/NLB and its integration with ECS.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "public_zone" {
  name         = var.domain_suffix
  private_zone = false
}
```

During terraform plan it comes up with this error:

```
Error: no matching Route53Zone found

  on ../prod/modules/regional-service/data.tf line 12, in data "aws_route53_zone" "public_zone":
  12: data "aws_route53_zone" "public_zone" {
```

The Route53 code is below:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "a-record" {
  name    = local.regional_subdomain
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public_zone.id

  alias {
    name                   = data.aws_lb.bridged-lb.dns_name
    zone_id                = data.aws_lb.bridged-lb.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_health_check" "health_check" {
  port          = 443
  type          = "HTTPS"
  resource_path = "/version"

  fqdn = local.regional_subdomain

  failure_threshold = "5"
  request_interval  = "30"

  tags = local.tags
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cname" {
  name            = local.global_subdomain
  records         = [local.regional_subdomain]
  set_identifier  = "${var.service_name}-${var.region}"
  ttl             = "60"
  type            = "CNAME"
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.public_zone.id
  health_check_id = aws_route53_health_check.health_check.id

  latency_routing_policy {
    region = var.region
  }
}
```

I will appreciate any help in resolving this issue.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is that Route53 zone in that AWS account?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I just realised that I might be in the wrong account. Let me look at this and get back to you, please.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I have now obtained the right account details and the right matching public hosted zone and everything is fine now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @ydaetskcoR, I looked at the code again and was able to realise that I was referencing the wrong AWS account. I immediately obtained the right account information and corresponding public hosted zones and my CI/CD pipeline process proceeded to complete well.